# A view to show worked time per task per user?

Tags: mysql

[I have written this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/611a7/1)

```
CREATE TABLE task
    (`taskid` int, `description` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`taskid`))
;

INSERT INTO task
    (`taskid`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (2,'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;

CREATE TABLE worktime
    (`taskid` int, `user` varchar(7), `startwork` datetime , `endwork` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO worktime
    (`taskid`, `user`, `startwork`, `endwork`)
VALUES
    (1, 'dirk', '2015-07-26 15:19:46', '2015-07-26 15:20:46'),
    (1, 'dirk', '2015-07-26 17:19:46', '2015-07-26 18:11:46'),
    (2, 'dirk', '2011-02-26 11:19:46', '2011-02-26 12:11:46'),
    (2, 'tim', '2011-02-26 11:19:46', '2011-02-26 12:11:46')
;
```

**What I want** is : Find the total time a user spent on a task.

E.g. say for task 1 and user dirk this would be 01:01 hours:minutes for task 1.

How can i create this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to add a `userID` to your `worketime` table instead of `User` and also the name `user` is reserved word so don't use it. The view you are looking for is made like this

```
CREATE VIEW user_task_time as select `user`,taskid,sec_to_time(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(endwork,startwork)))) as timeWorked FROM worktime GROUP BY user,taskid;
```

`TIMEDIFF()` return a time value and it is converted to second and back to time because `SUM()` function does not return correct results when used by time data type.